# Parsing aws cli via jq into CSV

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, iteration, export-to-csv, jq

AWS CLI output going to jq to parse into CSV.

This works:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-acls |jq -r '.NetworkAcls[].Entries[] | [.RuleNumber, .Protocol, .Egress, .CidrBlock, .RuleAction] |@csv'
```

but this does not:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-acls |jq -r '.NetworkAcls[].VpcId + "," + .NetworkAcls[].NetworkAclId + "," .NetworkAcls[].Entries[] | [.RuleNumber, .Protocol, .Egress, .CidrBlock, .RuleAction]'
```

> jq: error (at :274): Cannot index string with string "NetworkAcls"

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, showing the (possibly simplified) JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a bit careful about iteration with `[]` to avoid loops within loops within loops ...

With the following filter:

```
.NetworkAcls[]
| [.VpcId, .NetworkAclId]
 + (.Entries[] | [.RuleNumber, .Protocol, .Egress, .CidrBlock, .RuleAction])
| @csv
```

I get:

```
"vpc-e68f6f8d","acl-b6d916dd",100,"-1",true,"0.0.0.0/0","allow"
"vpc-e68f6f8d","acl-b6d916dd",32767,"-1",true,"0.0.0.0/0","deny"
"vpc-e68f6f8d","acl-b6d916dd",100,"-1",false,"0.0.0.0/0","allow"
"vpc-e68f6f8d","acl-b6d916dd",32767,"-1",false,"0.0.0.0/0","deny"
```